# ¿Cómo puedo crear un fichero svg?

Tags: android, html, html5, svg

Tengo un `svg` creado en una página de HTML.

Por ejemplo, para simplificar, podemos tomar este ejemplo sencillo:

```html
<svg>
  <circle r="60px" fill="red" cx="90" cy="65"></circle>
</svg>
```

Y me gustaría poder utilizarlo en Android. He visto que para ello lo que se puede hacer es crear un fichero `svg` e importarlo, sin embargo, no sé como crear ese fichero y en la mayoría de sitios me dicen como exportar a un fichero `svg` una imagen (es decir, una conversión) pero yo quiero introducir en un fichero `svg` el `svg` que muestro en el ejemplo anterior.

Por lo tanto, me surgen un par de dudas:

- ¿Un fichero `svg` tiene que tener alguna estructura en particular? Así como `HTML` tiene la siguiente estructura:

  `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`
- En caso de que no tenga ninguna estructura en particular ¿Se introduciría el `svg` tal cual lo tengo en el ejemplo anterior? Es decir, ¿se introduciría el `svg` con las mismas etiquetas que en el HTML?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con _"yo quiero introducir en un fichero svg el svg que muestro en el ejemplo anterior"_? ¿Quieres poner el círculo dentro de un fichero con más formas o qué pretendes exactamente?

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Me refería a poder importar ese svg como icono en Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Crear archivo .SVG

Estructura base de un icono archivo `.svg` modificar el `<path...` con el trazo del icono que quieras

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1" viewBox="0 0 24 24" enable-background="new 0 0 24 24" width="48" height="48">
   <path d="M 21 1.90625 L 18.46875 4.4375 C 16.708893 2.9398748 14.471062 2 12 2 C 6.4666667 2 2 6.4666667 2 12 C 2 17.533333 6.4666667 22 12 22 C 17.533333 22 22 17.533333 22 12 L 20 12 C 20 16.466667 16.466667 20 12 20 C 7.5333333 20 4 16.466667 4 12 C 4 7.5333333 7.5333333 4 12 4 C 13.922816 4 15.66022 4.6972027 17.0625 5.84375 L 14.90625 8 L 21 8 L 21 1.90625 z"></path>
</svg>
```

#### Importar archivo .SVG

Para usar un `svg` en un proyecto Android, lo debes convertir a  `vector drawables` para eso, te sitúas encima del directorio `Drawables`en `Android-Studio` abres el menú contextual y selecionas `New->Vector Asset`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se te abrirá un cuadro de diálogo, donde puedes cargar tu svg personalizado:

Selecciona `Local Files`

- **Name:** identificador para poder hacer referencia como un drawable normal.
- **Path:** ruta del svg
- **Tamaño:** definir el tamaño por defecto, normalmente es `24x24` si es para iconos de botón, siempre puedes rescalarlo directamente con `width` y `height` del componente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Documentación oficial [Crear interfaces dibujables en vector](https://developer.android.com/training/material/drawables.html?hl=es#VectorDrawables)

#### Modificar su color

Para cambiar el color, una vez pasado el `.svg` a `vector-drawable` en su .xml dentro del directorio `drawable` se puede especificar con `fillColor` con valor `ARGB`.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,17c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2s-0.9,-2 -2,-2 -2,0.9 -2,2 0.9,2 2,2zM18,8h-1L17,6c0,-2.76 -2.24,-5 -5,-5S7,3.24 7,6v2L6,8c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v10c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h12c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L20,10c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM8.9,6c0,-1.71 1.39,-3.1 3.1,-3.1s3.1,1.39 3.1,3.1v2L8.9,8L8.9,6zM18,20L6,20L6,10h12v10z"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: Hola @Webserveis, muchas gracias por la info. Esto me va a servir para el segundo paso pero realmente yo preguntaba por si el fichero svg tenía que tener una estructura interna al igual que HTML o en su defecto tendría que poner las etiquetas de svg en un fichero con la extensión .svg.

Comment: yo los importo de extensión .svg no he probado de los incrustado en html, complemento la información

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la parte en la que pone `path`. Entiendo que será una ruta pero, ¿qué debería de poner ahí?

Comment: @Error404 `path` no es una ruta. Se puede definir también como "trayecto". Para svg es un polígono que puede ser abierto o cerrado y rellenado con color la parte interior y el borde con distinto grosor. Lo que define es cada punto que forma parte del "camino" (otra traducción de path) y que haciendo la forma que quieres.

Comment: @Error404 con lo de path me refiero en poner el trazo del icono dentro de <path .... />

Comment: @Webserveis ¿Y cómo lo traduzco para que quede como lo has puesto tu? Es decir, ¿cómo sé como traducir el círculo que tengo yo ahora a un path de ese estilo?

Comment: prueba en poner <circle quitando <path y importa a androidstudio como vector-drawable, nunca lo he hecho con un circulo, yo los iconos los extraigo de los svg que encuentro por allí y casi todos son definidos en path

Comment: Vale, ya lo he conseguido. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar con el siguiente código:

```
<svg version="1.1"
     baseProfile="basic"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="120" height="120">
  <circle r="60px" fill="red" cx="90" cy="65"></circle>
</svg>
```

La versión puede ser 1.0, 1.1 ó 1.2 (todo dependerá de las propiedades de cada elemento, si están soportadas o no por la versión que utilices). Asimismo, 'baseProfile' está indicando que utilice lo básico (que seguramente soporta android).
Para comenzar tienes [Tutorial de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started).

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo que me faltaba era la versión y el xmlns.

Answer (score 1):

Los ficheros `svg` no tienen una estructura fija. Al ser fichero de etiquetado cuando no hay una etiqueta marcada toman un dato por defecto.

Pueden añadirse todas las formas que sean necesarias, con cuidado de que los identificadores no coincidan y creen ambigüedades.

NOTA: En caso de querer combinar varios elementos de distintos `svg` se debe tener cuidado de que no se tengan resultados inesperados (por ejemplo que un elemento tenga marcado un tamaño que en comparación con el tamaño que tenga marcado el otro haya una diferencia enorme que haga prácticamente que desaparezca uno, o que den valores por defecto que se solapen)

Comment: Entonces, si por ejemplo quiero que el círculo del ejemplo de la pregunta esté en un fichero `.svg` ¿simplemente tendría que copiar las etiquetas tal cual está en el HTML y crear un fichero con extensión `.svg`? Siento haber contestado tan tarde pero hoy no he tenido acceso a internet.

Comment: Sí, básicamente es eso, el problema es que al combinar las longitudes entre elementos de distintos svgs sean muy distintas o su origen de pintado o como decía los identificadores y te produciría fallos. Yo suelo usar [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/es/) si quiero hacer alguna composición. Al final te produce un archivo de texto definiendo todo lo que haz dibujado y puedes ver que básicamente es eso. También te agrega otra serie de etiquetas que le sirven InkScape para gestionar el archivo, pero que si borras otro gestor te dibujará igual.

Comment: Realmente yo sólo iba a usar un solo icono que iba a estar compuesto solamente de una etiqueta `<svg>` y algunos que otros `<g>` con círculos y líneas. No iba a combinar varios en uno ni nada por el estilo (realmente acabo de empezar con `svg` y no sé muy bien si te refieres a esto).

Comment: Te he puesto InkScape porque es gratuito y multiplataforma. Personalmente prefiero dibujar las formas que picar el código a mano. También puedes hacer los grupos que dices, ponerles identificadores e incluso aplicarles CSS si lo referencias en tu archivo.

Comment: ¡Gracias! La verdad que la información me sirve mucho. Al final he aceptado la respuesta de @Webserveis porque la he considerado la más completa. Un saludo :)